# Upload csv with Laravel for S3

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

I have a method that generates the file in csv using the Xlsx library and downloads it.
The place is working normally but I'm trying to move to s3.

Method that generates the csv and exports:

```
public function exporter($queryBuilder)
    {
        $this->exportData[] = [
            __('inscription.type_description_short_name'),
            __('inscription.type_description_short_email'),
            __('inscription.type_description_short_cpf'),
            __('inscription.type_description_short_phone'),
            __('inscription.type_description_short_status'),
            __('inscription.type_description_short_profile'),
            __('inscription.type_description_short_created_at'),
            __('inscription.type_description_short_updated_at'),
            __('Data Exclusão Lógica'),
        ];

        if ($queryBuilder->count() > 0) {
            $instance = $this;
            $queryBuilder->chunk(self::LIMIT_PAGE, function ($inscriptions) use ($instance) {
                foreach ($inscriptions as $value) {
                    $updatedAt = null;
                    $deletedAt = null;
                    if ($value->updated_at != null) {
                        $updatedAt = $value->updated_at->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
                    }
                    if ($value->deleted_at != null) {
                        $deletedAt = $value->deleted_at->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
                    }

                    $instance->exportData[] = [
                        $value->name,
                        $value->email,
                        Helper::mask($value->cpf, '###.###.###-##'),
                        Helper::mask($value->phone, '(##) ####-####'),
                        $value->inscriptionStatus->status,
                        $value->inscriptionProfile->profile,
                        $value->created_at->format('d/m/Y H:i:s'),
                        $updatedAt,
                        $deletedAt
                    ];
                }
            });
        }

        $filename = sprintf(
            'EVENTO_%s_RELACAO_DE_INSCRITOS_%s',
            strtoupper(Str::snake(Event::find(JWTAuth::getPayload()->get('event_id'))->name)),
            date('Ymd_His')
        );

        return Storage::disk('s3')->put($this->exportData , file_get_contents($filename),  'public');
    }
```

Route that downloads the csv and removes the file afterwards.

```
Route::get('export_entity/{filename}', function ($filename) {

    $filePath = storage_path('app/public/temp/' . $filename);

    return Storage::download($filePath, $filename)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
});
```

Erro:

> {"errors":[{"debugMessage":"Undefined variable:
> request","message":"Internal server
> error","extensions":{"category":"internal"},"locations":[{"line":2,"column":3}],"path":["exportInscription"],"trace":[{"file":"/back/app/Entities/Inscription.php","line":322,"call":"Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError(8,
> 'Undefined variable: request',
> '/back/app/Entities/Inscription.php', 322, array(3))"},

Comment: Your error is here: `file_get_contents($request->file)`. You do not have `$request` being passed to your export function.

Comment: I changed the variable to filename.
The CSV is not uploaded from the computer, it is generated via the $ this-> exportData variable